# Can you use Dijkstra's algorithm if there is a negative weight so long as there are no cycles?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory

**Update**:  I really botched the original question.  My original title was "Why do we first do a topological sort for acyclic weighted digraph shortest path problems?" but my question content was about Dijkstra's algorithm.  Hopefully since I've changed the title, the question is updated in such a way that it is useful to someone else. The answer to the updated question title is "**yes**".

**Original question**:

Why do I need to do a topological sort first? [(see code here)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/AcyclicSP.java.html)  Can't I just use Dijkstra's algorithm shown below and avoid the topological sort altogether (little messy syntax-wise but you get the idea)

```
MinIndexedPriorityQueue waitingEdges = new MinIndexedPriorityQueue
Graph g //some weighted directed graph
double[] distTo = new double[g.vertexCount]
Edge[] edgeTo = new Edge[g.vertexCount]
int source = //init to some value

void minPathInit()
    init distTo to double.MAX_VALUE
    //init first node
    distTo [source] = 0
    visit(source)
    while waitingEdges.count>0
        int vertex = waitingEdges.dequeue()
        relax(vertex )

void relax(v) //note that visit has been renamed to relax
    for each edge in graph.getEdgesFrom(v)
        int to= edge.to
        if edge.weight + distTo [edge.from]<  distTo [to]
            distTo[to] = edge.weight + distTo [edge.from]
            edgeTo[to] = edge
            if waitingEdges.contains(to)
                waitingEdges.change(to,  distTo[to] )
            else
                waitingEdges.enqueue(to,  distTo[to] )


//after everything is initialized
getPathTo(v)
    if not hasBeenVisited[v]
        return null
    Stack path = new Stack
    while edgeTo[v] != source
        path.push(edgeTo[v])
        v = edgeTo[v].from
    return path
```

I can understand why Dijkstra's algorithm can't handle negative cycles (because it would get stuck in an infinite loop) but if there are no negative cycles, why does it fail as shown (and require the topological sort first)

**Update:** Ok, I can see that I've botched up this question so I will try to fix it up a bit with an update.  Thanks for taking the time to point the hole's out for me.  I mistakenly thought [AcyclicSP](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/AcyclicSP.java.html) becomes Dijkstra's algorithm when removing the topological sort which is not the case.

However, my question about Dijkstra's algorithm (using the version shown above) remains.  Why can't it be used even if there is a negative weight so long as there are no cycles?  There is a java version of [Dijkstra's algorithm here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/DijkstraSP.java.html).  Mine is very similar to this (since this guy's book is where I learned about it) but his example is probably easier to read for some of you.

Comment: Where is the topological sort in your post? And no, you don't need it for finding a path with Dijkstra from a source to destination.

Comment: Why the question is tagges with a `java` tag?

Comment: Not only do you not need to do a topological sort to find a shortest path, i don't see how doing one could help.

Comment: @Tom Anderson, I suspect it avoids a bug in the implementation. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - Don't say it this way, it is a feature:)

Comment: @harold, I suspect he mean acyclic (spell checker bug?), but it doesn't matter if its cyclic or not.

Comment: @Everyone - I updated the question. Sorry there was a mistake in my original assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't make any topological sort in the original algorithm. But in the case of an a-cyclic graph, then you can decrees the running time to O(V) (while the original running time is O(|V|*log(|V|)).
The reason is that you sort in O(|V|) time, and then you can use that order, and don't need any heap (or priority queue). So the over all time decreases to O(|V|).

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't appear to require a topological sort.  Perhaps doing so avoids a bug you have in your implementation.

Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't support negative path costs, but **does** handle looping cycles. It does this by stopping when it finds that there is a shorter path to a node. A looping path will not be shorter and there for stop (provided the cost is non-negative)

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Perhaps I extracted something incorrectly from the book I'm reading but it seemed to imply that I had to use an algorithm other than Dijkstra's algorithm for solving graphs with no cycles that have negative weights. But if there are no cycles, perhaps I can still use Dijkstra's.  Is this true?

Comment: As I said `Dijkstra's algorithm ... does handle looping cycles` Its only negative weights it is not guaranteed to handle. BTW: Negative weights are difficult to make any sense of. E.g. say you have a garden with many paths and the weights are lengths, the ones with negative weights are those with a negative length e.g. -5 meters long.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand that it handles cycles if there are no negative paths.  Will it work for a graph that has some negative paths but no cycles?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't.  With a positive path, you can't pass over it more than once and set the shortest path. With negative paths, if you could pass over it more than once, the problem becomes unsolvable. Its similar to trying to find the longest path with cycles and positive path weights.

Comment: @Peter It wouldn't. Try this directed graph with source 'a' (it's even acyclic): 
           V = {a,b,c,d}, 
           E = {(a,b,6),(b,d,-4),(a,c,4),(c,d,1)}

Comment: Negative weights can make sense. Rather than a garden, consider a ski resort, where edges are runs, and weights are height changes. You want to ski downhill, which is fun, but not uphill, which is hard. And before you object that any route from A to B must involve the same net height change, remember that some ascents have ski-lifts!

Comment: @Tom Anderson, A good example. In this case the weights in each direction are different and the problem is solvable.

Comment: @Simone, Not sure what you are referring to with `It wouldn't` Your example doesn't appear to refer to any of the three statements I made.

Comment: @Tom Anderson, The only problem with the ski-lift example, is if you say that a ski-lift costs 1 and the run next to it is -10, then every time you go up and come down your total get -9 lower.  The lowest total weight route is to go round and round infinitely.

Comment: A model which accurately recapitulates the essential features of skiing holidays!

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I'm referring to your comment just above mine. i8abug writes " Will it work for a graph that has some negative paths but no cycles?" and you answered "I don't see why it wouldn't" and i answered you that it wouldn't and my example proves that

Comment: @Simone, In your example, the solution would be a -> b, b -> d for a total cost of 6 + -4 = 2. (Assuming you are going from a -> d) I don't see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use Dijkstra Algo with negative weights.
Hundreds have tried, no one was successfull.

Use Bellman-Ford Algo if you have neg. Weights